# proxy configuration in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, proxy, socks

I have problem with proxy in Eclipse 3.7.2 in Ubuntu 12.04. Eclipse is installed from Ubuntu repository.

I have configured HTTP, and HTTPS proxy in Network Preferences and keep SOCKS clear as many people recommends. But eclipse anyway says HTTP Proxy Authentication Required.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Set system-wide proxy settings in Ubuntu network configuration dialog.

In eclipse.ini add the following line: -Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient

In Eclipse in Network Connections set Active Provider to "native".

Comment: "native" provider doesn't work at all for Eclipse 4.7.3a and Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't work because I use OpenJDK. If use oracle's java with eclipse proxy configuration in standard dialog works fine.